# WITH RECURSIVE query with android room

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

Need to get rows with last 10 recent dates from table, even if some of the dates are missing from table.

This query is working fine to get dates but the problem is same query in android room dao throwing compile error at 'SELECT x+1' x cannot be resolved.

```
@Query(WITH RECURSIVE
 stepDtailsTable(x) AS (
        SELECT 0
        UNION ALL
        SELECT x + 1 FROM stepDtailsTable
        LIMIT(SELECT((julianday('2019-03-20')-julianday('2019-03-01')))+1)
        )
        SELECT date(julianday('2019-03-01'),'+'||x||' days')as date FROM stepDtailsTable")
StepDetailsPojo getLastTenDayData();
```

Comment: Why do you need to use RECURSIVE for selecting the last ten dates? If you use a different query then the problem may go away.

Comment: Any hint of different query? I am not having much exp on sql queries.. and requirement is to get last 10 days data from table even some days data is not present in table, if data is not there I need to show values as 0..

Comment: Something like `select * from stepDtailsTable order by thedatefield desc limit 10`

Comment: If table has rows with date 1,2,3,6,8,11..  with this query we can get 6 rows with desc order, but I need missing dates as well like 10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1.. so that for missing dates I can show 0 values,, in last ten days graph..

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood 'missing'. Yes, `recursive` is good in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that you are using constants for the julian dates whereas you wanted to query the last 10 recent dates from a table. Here is a query that does that, with filling gaps from the maximum date found in the table to 10 days earlier. I cannot test on your platform so it may not resolve the compiler error you are getting, maybe because `RECURSIVE` is not supported. Hopefully it gets you a step further.

```
WITH RECURSIVE
 cte(x) AS (
    SELECT julianday(date(max(thedate))) from TheDataTable  
    UNION ALL
    SELECT x-1 FROM cte
    LIMIT 10
)
SELECT date(x) FROM cte
```